# Red Display Bug in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics

Today, I reinstalled Windows 10 (without deleting personal data). Now the GUI is sometimes just showing strang red Bars or even painting the whole window in red.

What I tried to solve the issue:

- Deinstall Graphics Driver with DDU and Reinstall it
- All other drivers are up to date.
- Restart does not solve the issue

I also have a second Windows user, which does not have this symptoms, so I'm pretty sure this is some settings error. Both user profiles where there befor reinstalling Windows.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue (apart from deleting the old profile and just make a new one, which i will do if no other solutions come up).

Here are two screenshots to demonstrate the problem, but the error occurs in different places (no application so far though):

- [When starting an invalid file shortcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMo3d.png)
- [When selecting / changing current location in the file explorer (as camera photo, since it deselect everything and nothing can be seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyaf1.jpg)

Comment: Could be a theme issue... try resetting to default? https://www.tenforums.com/customization/93493-how-reset-windows-10-theme-default.html or http://www.sussex.ac.uk/its/help/faq?faqid=2856

Comment: [https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/165667-how-reset-settings-app-windows-10-a.html](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/165667-how-reset-settings-app-windows-10-a.html) perhaps try Option 1 there, and then change your theme/personalization to a different one and then back to your current one. Restart computer. Log back in and see if that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. While the reset from https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/165667-how-reset-settings-app-windows-10-a.html did not help (alone), the issue did resolve after changing themes. Not sure if the reset was necessary but didn't hurt either. If one of you would turn there Comment into an answer?